# c# database sql inner join

Tags: c#, sql, database, inner-join

I want to inner join my ActivityClub table with Clubs table so it can be updated into 2 tables. I'm using method class and SQL database.

> `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.'`

```
 public int updateactivity(string clubname, string clubdesc, string activity, string achv)
    {
        int status = 0;
        string updateSQL = "UPDATE ActivityClub SET club_desc=@desc, activity=@act, achievement=@acv INNER JOIN Clubs AS C1 ON C1.club_desc = Activity.club_desc WHERE club_name=@club";
        Connect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, conn);
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", clubname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", clubdesc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@act", activity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acv", achv);
        status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: which db you are using ???

Comment: If you need to update more than one table you'll have to do multiple Update commands.

Comment: However if you need to determine what rows to update in one table based on something in another table you have to do something like this `Update a Set Bar=@Bar From TableToUpdate a Join AnotherTable b on a.Id = b.Aid Where b.Foo = @Foo`

Comment: "so it can be updated into 2 tables" - no,  No do. There is no SQL dialect under the sun I am aware of in which an update can update 2 tables at the same time. You can join (to filter) but every update only ever updates ONE table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect syntax. It should be like this. I would suggest you write a stored procedure and use query in the SP and call it from C# code.

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t1.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```

Reference: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you need this syntax (Update table set clause ...FROM table JOIN table ON clause...)

```
     string updateSQL = 
        "UPDATE ActivityClub 
        SET club_desc=@desc, activity=@act, achievement=@acv 
        FROM ActivityClub
        INNER JOIN Clubs AS C1 ON C1.club_desc = Activity.club_desc 
        WHERE club_name=@club";
```